# Texture suddenly behaves crazy

Tags: texturing, materials

I hope you can help with this. I use Blender 3.5.

I have a model of a human head in Blender with texture on it. Everything looks good after I have finished the node setup in shading.
But after a while, the texture suddenly goes crazy and looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The strange thing is that this happens even though I do not touch anything in the node setup in Shading. It seems to happen out of nowhere. Sometimes, it happens when I swift viewport settings from Rendered Preview to Material preview and back to Rendered Preview. Then the texture turns into a wrong colour (much darker) and bursts into a strange abstract shape. I do not understand why the texture can suddenly behave so differently just by changing the preview, while not touching anything in the actual node setup.

If you need it this is the node setup below. As mentioned, it works totally fine at first, but after changing the viewport settings, it is almost like the texture explodes out of nowhere. Sometimes it also happens just by reopening the .blend-file.

[image]

Just to note: There should not be a problem with the linked images, both for the texture displacement or roughness map. I have tried to relink them several times. I have also tried to pack all external files into the .blend file but the error still occurs.

(Don't know if it has any relevance: the problem started after I tried to add a Subsurface Scattering Map. It didnt work, so I removed it again (as you can see, it is not present in the node setup anymore). It would be strange if this could this cause problems after removal, but I wanted to mention it, just in case).

Any suggestions of how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: pls provide blend file with packed resources so we can check it out, thx

Comment: 99.999% probablity that the scale on the diplacement node is too much. Try lowring it. (If not that then pleasse share the file)

Comment: Thank you! The packed blend file is available on this wetransfer link. I hope it works - if not, I can also upload it by other means: https://we.tl/t-eKp87MNpuN

Comment: I agree with @TheKalaakaar. Drop the Scale of the Displacement node to .01 and it behaves itself. Increase it to .02 and you start to get distortions appearing. (You should also Shade Smooth your object. by the way.)